# Connect cold faucet to washing machine's hot inlet to test internal connectivity?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, appliances, washing-machine, laundry

In the absence of a working water heater, is it okay to connect a cold water faucet to a modern H-E washing machine's hot inlet to test the machine's internal tubing for leaks by running a warm or hot full wash cycle? If so, can I use a Y-connector to split the cold faucet to both cold and hot inlets?

Will it cause any damages or malfunction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't damage the machine I have seen this done where the home owner only wants to use cold water. Having both connected keeps water in the hot solenoid and having 2 solenoids running the machine on warm it will fill faster but still be cold. Some machines will throw an error if there is no pressure so this solves several problems.